# Clickable html email not showing images

Tags: html-email, email-signature

I am having some issues with my clickable email signature. I made an email signature in Adobe Photoshop and tried to paste it for my Outlook mails. It used to work in past, but now it does not show any more as it should. I can open it in my internet browser, but when pasting it and at the preview it in Outlook my signature doesn’t display correctly, it doesn`t show the images, only small thumbnail logo, sometimes not even that. I have all of my settings allowing HTML in Outlook, maybe there is a problem or something that could be done better in my code.

This is one of my images (the easiest one not containing any info):
[Mail-14.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rrBwn.png)

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Email-sign</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<meta name="color-scheme" content="light dark">
<meta name="supported-color-schemes" content="light dark">
<style media="screen" type="text/css">
    td {line-height:0; font-size: 0.0em; }
    img { display: block; float: left; padding: 0; align: absbottom; align: texttop; }
</style>
</head> 
<body bgcolor="#FFFFFF" leftmargin="0" topmargin="0" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0">
<table id="Table_01" width="301" height="136" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    <tr>
        <td colspan="10">
            <img src="images/Email-sign_01.png" width="300" height="47" alt=""></td>
        <td>
            <img src="spacer.gif" width="1" height="47" alt=""></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="4">
            <img src="images/Email-sign_02.png" width="137" height="20" alt=""></td>
        <td rowspan="2">
            <a href="https://si.linkedin.com/in">
                <img src="images/Linkedin.png" width="19" height="21" border="0" alt=""></a></td>
        <td rowspan="2">
            <a href="https://wa.me/+49xxxxxxx">
                <img src="images/Whatsapp.png" width="18" height="21" border="0" alt=""></a></td>
        <td rowspan="2">
            <a href="skype:myname?chat">
                <img src="images/Skype.png" width="20" height="21" border="0" alt=""></a></td>
        <td rowspan="8">
            <img src="images/Email-sign_06.png" width="6" height="88" alt=""></td>
        <td rowspan="7">
            <img src="images/QrCode.png" width="73" height="73" alt=""></td>
        <td rowspan="8">
            <img src="images/Email-sign_08.png" width="27" height="88" alt=""></td>
        <td>
            <img src="spacer.gif" width="1" height="20" alt=""></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2" rowspan="2">
            <img src="images/Email-sign_09.png" width="93" height="18" alt=""></td>
        <td colspan="2" rowspan="2">
            <a href="tel:+49xxxx">
                <img src="images/Tel.png" width="44" height="18" border="0" alt=""></a></td>
        <td>
            <img src="spacer.gif" width="1" height="1" alt=""></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="3">
            <a href="tel:+49xxxxx">
                <img src="images/Tel-11.png" width="57" height="17" border="0" alt=""></a></td>
        <td>
            <img src="spacer.gif" width="1" height="17" alt=""></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td rowspan="5">
            <img src="images/Email-sign_12.png" width="84" height="50" alt=""></td>
        <td colspan="6">
            <a href="mailto:myemail@mydomain.mycom">
                <img src="images/Mail.png" width="110" height="17" border="0" alt=""></a></td>
        <td>
            <img src="spacer.gif" width="1" height="17" alt=""></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2">
            <a href="mailto:myemail@mydomain.mycom">
                <img src="images/Mail-14.png" width="33" height="1" border="0" alt=""></a></td>
        <td colspan="4" rowspan="2">
            <a href="https://mydomain.mycom">
                <img src="images/Website.png" width="77" height="15" border="0" alt=""></a></td>
        <td>
            <img src="spacer.gif" width="1" height="1" alt=""></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2" rowspan="3">
            <img src="images/Email-sign_16.png" width="33" height="32" alt=""></td>
        <td>
            <img src="spacer.gif" width="1" height="14" alt=""></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="4" rowspan="2">
            <img src="images/Email-sign_17.png" width="77" height="18" alt=""></td>
        <td>
            <img src="spacer.gif" width="1" height="3" alt=""></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <img src="images/Email-sign_18.png" width="73" height="15" alt=""></td>
        <td>
            <img src="spacer.gif" width="1" height="15" alt=""></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <img src="spacer.gif" width="84" height="1" alt=""></td>
        <td>
            <img src="spacer.gif" width="9" height="1" alt=""></td>
        <td>
            <img src="spacer.gif" width="24" height="1" alt=""></td>
        <td>
            <img src="spacer.gif" width="20" height="1" alt=""></td>
        <td>
            <img src="spacer.gif" width="19" height="1" alt=""></td>
        <td>
            <img src="spacer.gif" width="18" height="1" alt=""></td>
        <td>
            <img src="spacer.gif" width="20" height="1" alt=""></td>
        <td>
            <img src="spacer.gif" width="6" height="1" alt=""></td>
        <td>
            <img src="spacer.gif" width="73" height="1" alt=""></td>
        <td>
            <img src="spacer.gif" width="27" height="1" alt=""></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Try using full path reference to the image files. For example, instead of `src="images/Email-sign_01.png"` you must use `src="https://yourdomain.com/images/Email-sign_01.png"`. Hope this resolves your bug

Comment: I tried that also and it does not work. I have this locally on my pc.
I open my signature in Chrome or Edge, copy it and paste it in email signatures or in an email. 
And it used to work sometimes with some signatures, but now it doesn`t.

Comment: please create a `jsfiddle` using `[<>]`. Lack of images here, that you are using, is an issue to work on the code. Edit your question and Look for `[<>]` above the edit panel and create `jsfiddle`

Comment: I tried to put all of my images on my sites public html file and load it from online. When I load the code, it shows only small broken thumbnails. The images are loaded, they are in png format, but for some reason one mail signature shows at is should, the other does not, and the code is the same. Both of those signatures show normal in my browser preview.

Comment: Also when I try to paste it in MS Word it shows that there is something, but everything is blank. When I paste the other signature with the same html code, but just less images, the signature shows normally.

Comment: MS-Word handles Images differently. Also, there is an option to display images or not from the File->Options in MS-Word. So, don't relate it. Load the images here.